# Caves in Primordia Xenoblade X

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

How do I get into the caves (for collectables etc. ). I unlocked the rocky cave but can't find it again now. Also are some of the caves only got to by skell? I am too low level (16ish) to get skells and have only just completed chapter 4. The follow ball will not work for places, just missions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get into caves by going to them on the map. All except for maybe one or two are reachable without a Skell, although some of them are guarded by some high-level monsters (the one near the north-most point of Primordia, for example, is guarded by level 30s).

If it's not urgent to go to any cave in particular, it's easier to simply wait until you're a bit higher level before trekking throughout the land, looking for caves.